# Recommendation for a good image format conversion program

Tags: software-rec, photos, image-conversion

Does anyone know a good (and preferably free) program to make conversions like to change a format?
I want to get a image of 95 x 120 pixels from a photo I have in order to use a particular application web.
Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Preferably for Windows

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) for fast easy conversions, in most cases. It supports all the common formats. It is an awesome, easy to use photo editor, too. The resizing function is one of my favorites - it's customizable; you can use "Best Quality", Nearest-Neighbor, Bilinear/Bicubic, or Super-Sampling.

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), when it doesn't work. It's free and has lots of features, can open lots of formats, including PhotoShop, and stuff you've never even heard of before.

Comment: Can I use these programs on windows?

Comment: You can with GIMP.

Comment: @Peterstone: Paint.NET is Windows-only (I believe a Mono port exists, though) and GIMP is available for Windows and others.

Answer (score 4):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a suite of command-line programs that's available for Windows and other operating systems.

```
convert -resize 95x120 imagefile.ext outputfile.ext
```

will create a new file at the [requested size](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize). Many other operations including format conversion can be performed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you mean for windows, [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is pretty tough to beat for simple manipulations like resizing...

Comment: +1 for irfanview.  Low weight install, more formats than you could ever want, relatively simple interface